# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Could not find stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, webservice

Estoy intentando hacer un **WebMethod** que me obtenga toda la información de una tabla.

```
public void HelloWorld()
        {
            var Lista = new List<Atributos>();
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(cnn))
            {
                var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ASIGNATURA", con) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };
                con.Open();
                var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    var hambre = new Atributos
                    {
                        iD = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString()),
                        Nombre = dr[1].ToString(),
                        Credito = Convert.ToInt32(dr[2].ToString())

                    };
                    Lista.Add(hambre);
                }
            }
            var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(Lista));
        }
```

Esta es la clase Atributos:

```
public class Atributos
    {
        public int iD { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public int Credito { get; set; }
    }
```

Esta es la tabla Asignatura

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me da este error y no se como solucionar. Ni siquiera entiendo porque se produce el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero alguien me ayude! Gracias!!

Comment: Que error, dices que te presenta?

Comment: Perdona, puse la imagen incorrecta. Ahi esta el error.

Comment: Ahi dice que no encuentra el Storage procedure, SELECT * FROM ASIGNATURA

Comment: elimina: { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };

Comment: solo agregas el { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };, cuando trabajes con SP, en este caso es solo un Sql statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta eliminando

```
 { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };


 var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ASIGNATURA", con);
                con.Open();
```

Estas llamando un sql statement, no un storage procedure.

Comment: Funciono perfectamente. Muchísimas gracias!!

Comment: de nada amigo!. exito

Answer (score -1):

el error esta en:

var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ASIGNATURA;", con) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };

te falta agregar el ; al final del query.

espero te sirva.